# Liferay 7.1 : call a javascript function after create journal article (web content)

Tags: liferay, liferay-7

I link my web content (journal article) with a custom table nammed 'ArticleZone'. I add in the edit_article.jsp a dropdown list to link an article to a zone.

Then, i need to save my 'ArticleZone' when i save the web content. I need to save it after the save of the web content because i need its ID.

Can i overpass the function of saving a journal article ?

How can i do that ? Any ideas ?

I've tested javascript call but my web content has not been saved before the javascript was called.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with a Service wrapper.

See https://dev.liferay.com/en/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/7-0/customizing-liferay-services-service-wrappers

With a service wrapper class that override `JournalArticleServiceWrapper` you can redefine main `addArticle` method.

In the body, after the `super.addArticle(...)` call you can invoke your custom save. Use the `serviceContext` parameter to inject custom data.

Comment: Thanks. It works and corresponds perfectly to my request. +1